# why file is not exist but lsof show this file not deleted

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel, lsof

`stat` a linux regular file, target file is not exist.  but `lsof` can found this file, and found a program opened this file. `lsof` show this file is normal.

I think this file must be deleted, but I cannot understand why `lsof` show this file is normal.

Comment: check this [post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68523/find-and-remove-large-files-that-are-open-but-have-been-deleted)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Read more about [i-nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). You never delete a file, but just an entry in some directory (associating name to i-nodes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to have a problem like you， The directory where the files are located is mount another disk.Try to unmount the disk, maybe you can found your files.
Or, the disk where your files located maybe unmount by force.